# AT commands SM 0,0

Tags: sms, at-command

I'm new at AT commands, and I'm having an issue when I try to receive a SMS in my SIM card.

It's a D-link DWM-157 (I guess that's it).

How I'm doing:

```
AT
OK
AT+CMGF=1
OK
AT+CPMS?
+CPMS: "SM", 0, 0, "SM", 0, 0, "SM", 0, 0
```

and then it returns the SM as 0,0, **as if the SIM card had no max SMS storage capacity**.

I tried plugging off and on again the modem and sometimes it works just fine, but when I reset it again, the problem comes back.

Can you guys help me understanding what's going on?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? Do you still need help?